# In what program is 247freepoker.com done?

Tags: javascript

By accident I landed on this old poker site - https://www.247freepoker.com/ - it looks awesome and I am trying to figure out what is this coded in? It is not Flash and it doesn't look like html thing (since I can't select text). Is it Javascript or something else?

Answer (score 2):

It's JavaScript / HTML 5, specifically the game is using [HTML 5 Canvas](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html), which is fairly typical for games on the web post-flash.

Note however that a lot of tools export games to HTML 5, and use the Canvas to do so. The very popular [Unity](https://unity.com/) game engine, for example, has options to export projects to run in canvas on the web. So its worth noting that this probably wasn't coded from scratch in JavaScript (although it *could* have been).